# Sparkjava upload file to public

Tags: java, file-upload, spark-java

I am trying to upload file to my public location. I searched a couple of examples, and tried almost all of them but couldn't upload file into my public location. Here is my code :

```
File uploadDir = new File("upload");
uploadDir.mkdir();
post("/admin/upload", "multipart/form-data", (req, response) -> {


            Path tempFile = Files.createTempFile(uploadDir.toPath(), "", "");

            req.attribute("org.eclipse.jetty.multipartConfig", new MultipartConfigElement("/temp"));

            try (InputStream input = req.raw().getPart("uploaded_file").getInputStream()) { // getPart needs to use same "name" as input field in form
                Files.copy(input, tempFile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            }

            return "<h1>You uploaded this image:<h1><img src='" + tempFile.getFileName() + "'>";


        });
```

This code creates file into the root of the project folder. [image: Uploaded folder]

This is the created folder but I want to put my files into the folder below or the same folder inside the target folder:
 
[image: Uploaded folder]

And I also changed uploadDir folder with **/public/upload/images**, **/public/upload**, **public/upload/images**, **public/upload/images** etc.. I almost tried anything but couldn't find the result

Comment: So the problem is that the file is uploaded but not to the folder you wanted?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: And what did you set `staticFiles.externalLocation()` to?

Comment: Just "/public" folder

Comment: Does the `try` block throw an exception? Try to catch it and see if the problem is there.